# QGIS 3.10.3: label callouts are not appearing

Tags: qgis, labeling

The [3.10 changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/) mentions that label callouts are now available.  However I have not been able to get them to display, no matter what values and options I enter in the Layer Styling > Callouts window.  That is, no lines extend from labels to features.  Instead, I get the previous version labels, which are centered over the features.

I also tried with 3.12; no joy.

What am I missing?

Comment: After ensuring the 'Draw callouts' checkbox in the Callouts tab, set the 'placement' setting to 'cartographic' and 1-2mm from symbol bounds. You won't see a callout unless the label is a distance from the symbol. This will be a way to test the callouts are working by moving all the labels en masse away from the symbols.

Comment: @DPSSpatial Great, that worked (convert your comment to an answer and I'll credit you).  I was getting thrown-off by the Callouts Tab > "Offset from feature" and "Offset from label area" settings, think that they would do what your answer explains.  But now I see that those two settings control the *space* between the callout line and feature symbol and label text, respectively.

Comment: OK Great! I've added that answer. Thanks, and glad that helped!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After ensuring the 'Draw callouts' checkbox in the Callouts tab, set the 'placement' setting to 'cartographic' and 1-2mm from symbol bounds.

You won't see a callout unless the label is a distance from the symbol.

This will be a way to test the callouts are working by moving all the labels en masse away from the symbols.

Comment: I'm adding a followup comment to any future viewers, and to myself in case I refer back to this thread: I had mistakenly assumed that after checking the "Draw Callouts" box, QGIS would automatically move my labels and insert the callouts.  That is, the labels would be somehow "spread out".  Not so!  Rather, I had to manually move my labels away from their respective feature using the "Moves a Label or Diagram" button, located in the the Label toolbar.  Once the label was moved beyond the placement offset, Voila! the callout would appear.